# Getting [OBJECT][OBJECT] in data table

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, httprequest

**Apex class**

```java
public class IndianPostDataService {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getDetailsUsingPincode(string PINCODE){
        
       Http http= new Http();
       HttpResponse response=new HttpResponse();
        
       HttpRequest request=new HttpRequest();
        
       request.setEndpoint('https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/'+PINCODE);
       request.setMethod('GET');
        
       response=http.send(request);   
       system.debug(response.getBody());

       return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Indian Postal" icon-name="utility:anywhere_alert">
      
     <div class="slds-p-around_medium slds-grid slds-wrap">

        <div class="slds-size_2-of-3">
            <div class=" slds-m-around_x-small">
                 <lightning-input  label="Enter Pincode" placeholder="Enter 6 Digit PinCode" onchange={handlePinChange}></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
            <div class=" slds-m-around_x-small slds-p-top_large">
                <lightning-button label="Enter" onclick={handleClick}> </lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>

     </div>

     <div class="slds-p-around_medium" if:true={showMe}> 
          
        <table class="slds-p-around_medium">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Branch Type</th>
                    <th>Delivery Status</th>
                    <th>Circle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template for:each={pinDetails.data} for:item="dat">
                    <tr key={dat.Name}>
                        <td>{dat.Name}</td>
                        <td>{dat.BranchType}</td>
                        <td>{dat.DeliveryStatus}</td>
                        <td>{dat.Circle}</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement,track,wire } from 'lwc';
import getDetailsUsingPincode from '@salesforce/apex/IndianPostDataService.getDetailsUsingPincode';

export default class PinCode extends LightningElement {
    @track showMe=false;
    @track pinCode;
    @track pinDetails;
    @track error;
    
    handlePinChange(event){
        this.pinCode=event.target.value;
    }

    @wire (getDetailsUsingPincode,{PINCODE:'$pinCode'}) accounts({error,data}){
        if(data){
           this.pinDetails=JSON.parse(data);
           this.error=undefined  
        }
        else if(error)
        {
           this.error=error;
           this.pinDetails=undefined;
        }
    } 

    handleClick(event)
    {
        // getDetailsUsingPincode({PINCODE:this.pinCode}).then((result)=>{
        //     this.datas=JSON.parse(result);
        //     alert ('data is'+this.datas);
        //     this.showMe=true;
        //  }).catch(err=>{
        //      alert('Error')
        //  })
           this.showMe=true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a tour of [ask] to better understand the format of SFSE. Adding a description of the problem your are facing adds more value to the question than simply a copy/paste of your code

Answer (score 1):

```
<template for:each={pinDetails.data} for:item="dat">
```

Should be:

```
<template for:each={pinDetails.PostOffice} for:item="dat">
```

Also, for some reason, it appears it may be coming back as an array, which isn't consistent with the [documentation](http://www.postalpincode.in/Api-Details). Here's a working non-Salseforce version of the [code](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/XMY72TkNzO4AiEZxxDcQ/src/app.js?p=stories).

You'll see that I had to use the first element of the response (`this.pinDetails[0]`) to get this to work.

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  pinCode
  pinDetails = {}
  handlePinChange(event) {
    this.pinCode = event.target.value;
  }
  async handleClick() {
    const result = await fetch(`https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/${this.pinCode}`)
    this.pinDetails = await result.json();
    if(this.pinDetails[0]) {
      this.pinDetails = this.pinDetails[0];
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever you're having weird problems with an API, always check the output to see what you're actually getting. In any case, this should probably help you enough to get started.

---

I've uploaded this as a [repository](https://github.com/brianmfear/q373466) you can explore or clone as you desire. This runs in my org successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Change @wire method

I thing this change wrok will be fine

```
this.pinDetails=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringfy(response);

As you are assigning  the data alone to pinDetails, in template for each iteration there's no need to write pinDetails.data
Just write items={pinDetails}